# Spring Websocket with jetty broke mvc tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, websocket, jetty

I include a websocket to my project and then i have error wherever i use `@WebAppConfiguration`. So I try to find a problem and get that ServletContext is mocked and not instance of ContextHandler.Context
So how can i fix my MVC tests and use websockets in one project?

example of MVC test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PlayerControllerTest {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @InjectMocks
  private PlayerController playerController;

  @Test
  public void getById()
  throws Exception {

    when(playerService.find(0L)).thenReturn(region);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/player/{playerId}", 0L))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("playerName").value("Russia"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("id").value(0));

    verify(playerService, times(1)).find(0L);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(playerService);
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(playerController).build();
  }
}
```

Websocket config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  ServletContext servletContext;

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/supportChat")
        .setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler())
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS().setClientLibraryUrl("//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1.1.2/sockjs.min.js");
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {

    WebSocketPolicy policy = new WebSocketPolicy(WebSocketBehavior.SERVER);
    policy.setInputBufferSize(8192);
    policy.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1000));

    servletContext.setAttribute(DecoratedObjectFactory.ATTR, new DecoratedObjectFactory());
    return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(
        new JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(new WebSocketServerFactory(servletContext, policy)));
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages.simpDestMatchers("/app/supportChat/**", "/supportChat/**")
        .PermitAll();
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(8);
    registration.setInterceptors(presenceChannelInterceptor());
  }

  /**
   * Use for debug of STOMP over WebSocket.
   * @see PresenceChannelInterceptor
   */
  @Bean
  public PresenceChannelInterceptor presenceChannelInterceptor() {
    return new PresenceChannelInterceptor();
  }

  @Override
  protected void customizeClientInboundChannel(final ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.setInterceptors(new SubscribeInterceptor());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
    messageConverters.add(new GsonMessageConverter());
    return true;
  }
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start Jetty WebSocketServerFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start Jetty WebSocketServerFactory
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.jetty.JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.start(JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.doStart(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.start(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.WebSocketTransportHandler.start(WebSocketTransportHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.start(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.start(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping.start(WebSocketHandlerMapping.java:65)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.doStart(WebSocketServerFactory.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.jetty.JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy$ModernJettyWebSocketServerFactoryAdapter.startFactory(JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.jetty.JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy$WebSocketServerFactoryAdapter.start(JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.jetty.JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.start(JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:123)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Try specifying webenvironment to use a random port. Something like this  .@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApp.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too faced a similar issue 
The problem was with the web application context using a mocked port which failed to create required beans for jetty to operate.

For a spring boot application 
Try annotating

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApp.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

against your test class.
By default web environment uses a mocked port